# Sqlite - importing from CSv

Tags: sqlite, csv

I am importing a CSV into sqlite via the database manager tool. I have set the headings as the first row, however when it is imported the data is upside down. for instance:

in CSV file

```
A    B    C
1    6    5
3    2    1
     1    7
     9
```

in sqlite table

```
A    B    C
     9     
     1    7
3    2    1
1    6    5
```

is there a way for this not to happen?

Comment: Why do you care?  Do you realize that tables in a Relational Database are conceptually unordered?

Comment: There are many DB manager tools.